# Why are detectives/investigators referred to as "gumshoe"s?

Tags: colloquialisms

Why are detectives/inspectors colloquially referred to as Gumshoes?

Is it anything other that they would travel a lot in investigations and, presumably, wore hard-wearing shoes?

Comment: [Etymonline.com](http://Etymonline.com/) is a good resource for such questions, worthy of bookmarking.  You can read what they say about [gumshoe](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=gumshoe&searchmode=none_).

Comment: @J.R. Nice. Should this question be closed as general reference then since there's nothing more to the word than that?

Comment: That might be what ultimately happens.  I didn't vote to close, though, because there might be some more colorful story as to how detectives earned this name (as opposed to, say, nurses or garbage collectors – surely detectives weren't the only ones wearing those shoes, right?).  The Etymonline link provides a good start, but, in this case, its details are rather scant.  There may be a very interesting answer lurking out there somewhere – one that some linguistic gumshoe will uncover and share with us.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://www.word-detective.com/030299.html#gumshoe

> It turns out that the original "gumshoes" of the late 1800's were shoes
>   or boots made of gum rubber, the soft-soled precursors of our modern
>   sneakers... At the turn of the century "to gumshoe" meant to sneak
>   around quietly as if wearing gumshoes, either in order to rob or,
>   conversely, to catch thieves. "Gumshoe man" was originally slang for a
>   thief, but by about 1908 "gumshoe" usually meant a police detective,
>   as it has ever since.

---

http://www.randomhouse.com/wotd/index.pperl?date=19981110

> The primary modern use of gumshoe is as a noun meaning 'a private
>   detective'. This is a narrow remnant of a group of senses having to do
>   with stealth.
>
> Originally, gumshoe referred to a shoe with a rubber sole,
>   specifically, galoshes or (more relevant to our purposes) sneakers.
>   The senses of gumshoe leading to the 'private detective' sense all
>   have to do with the idea that rubber-soled shoes give the wearer the
>   ability to walk stealthily.
>
> The earliest examples show gumshoe used as an adjective meaning 'being
>   a stealthy or surreptitious thief or tracker', and thus 'being a
>   plainclothes police officer or a private detective'. This adjective is
>   first recorded in 1900 and occurs a number of times before 1910. A
>   secondary sense of the adjective, found at about the same time, is
>   '(of actions or activities) carried out stealthily or surreptitiously'
>   (e.g., "No gumshoe democratic campaign in Nebraska," from a 1904
>   newspaper).
>
> The noun in the sense 'a plainclothes police officer; (usually) a
>   private detective' is first recorded in 1906, as your source notes.
>   Less frequent noun senses are 'a police officer' and the military use
>   'an intelligence officer or a spy'.
>
> Some additional uses: the verb gumshoe 'to come or go stealthily;
>   sneak', from 1902; 'to work as a private detective', from 1908; gum,
>   gumfoot, gumboot, and gumheel, all meaning 'a private detective; and
>   gumshoe artist and gumshoer, both also meaning 'a private detective'.

Comment: _"The earliest examples show gumshoe used as an adjective meaning 'being a stealthy or surreptitious thief or tracker', and thus 'being a plainclothes police officer or a private detective'."_


That usage would be as a verb, not an adjective, right?